# Getting next cluster number in FAT12

Tags: assembly, operating-system, x86, bootloader, fat

I am using BrokenThorn's [tutorial](http://www.brokenthorn.com/Resources/OSDev6.html) for OS develpoment. My confusion is in this piece of code, which is responsible for reading the next cluster number of the file:

```
      mov     ax, WORD [cluster]  ; identify current cluster from FAT

 ; is the cluster odd or even? Just divide it by 2 and test!

      mov     cx, ax              ; copy current cluster
      mov     dx, ax              ; copy current cluster
      shr     dx, 0x0001          ; divide by two
      add     cx, dx              ; sum for (3/2)

      mov     bx, 0x0200          ; location of FAT in memory
      add     bx, cx              ; index into FAT
      mov     dx, WORD [bx]       ; read two bytes from FAT

      test    ax, 0x0001
      jnz     .ODD_CLUSTER
```

From my reading of online sources and threads, this is what I have found:

1. The first cluster number in the root directory entry for the file is of 2 bytes. For FAT12, only the lower 12 bits of these 2 bytes are used.
2. The FAT for FAT12 stores in the following format:
   `vwX uYZ` where `XYZ` is one cluster number and `uvw` is another. I have a question regarding this - which represents the lower numbered FAT entry and which represents the higher ?

However, seeing the code, I cannot understand how the above 2 facts(if assumed to be correct) are being used. Initially, `ax` has the 2 bytes from the root directory and its lower 12 bits can be used directly. But that is not being done. Also, how is the `vwX uYZ` format being parsed here ?

If someone could explain this in some detail and point out any mistakes I have made, it would be very helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The starting cluster number is used as an index into the FAT. Since it is FAT12, every 2 clusters correspond to 3 bytes.

> ax has the 2 bytes from the root directory and its lower 12 bits can be used directly. But that is not being done.

The whole 16 bits of ax are used. Since the higher 4 bits of ax will be 0 from the starting cluster number, that is equivalent to using only the lower 12 bits (unless there is a corrupted directory entry, which could make you index into nowhere).

> Also, how is the vwX uYZ format being parsed here ?

That is better put as `vw Xu YZ`. Recall that x86 is little-endian. When you read 2 bytes in x86, and they are stored as `vw Xu`, the actual number read is `Xuvw`. Mask to only keep the lower 12 bits and you get `uvw`. Similarly, when you read `Xu YZ`, the actual number read is `YZXu`. Shift right and you get `YZX`. Which, incidentally means that the actual format is likely to be `vw Zu XY`.

Comment: I don't think vw xu and yz are bytes of a cluster number, since vw xu would be 16-bit - well enough to hold 12-bit values. I guessed it meant two numbers with 3 nibbles (hex digits) each. That's what I meant with the "two pairs".

Comment: @turboscrew: miscommunication here. `vwZuXY` are 3 bytes on disk that correspond to 2 cluster numbers. After reading the 2 bytes corresponding to an even cluster number, you need to mask to get rid of the extraneous `Z`. After reading the 2 bytes corresponding to an odd cluster number, you need to shift right 4 bits to get rid of the extraneous `u`.

Comment: Very well explained. Helped me understand this by just one read ! Thanks a lot !!

Answer (score 0):

If you find a cluster number, say 10 (the firs cluster of the file is cluster #10), then the 10th FAT entry contains the second cluster number of that file. There are no pairs of cluster number. The previous cluster number is the table index.

If your file had the clusters 5, 7 and 9,:
The first cluster is #5 that you got from the directory.

The FAT looks like (X = don't care, belongs to some other file):

```
X (index = 0)
X
X
X
X
7 (index = 5)
X
9 (index = 7)
X
0xFFF (index = 9; enf of file marker)
```